# How to view auto variables in Visual Studio after entering break mode

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

While debugging a C# WPF program in Visual Studio, I pause the application using the pause sign **⏸** while the application is waiting on keyboard input.  (That is, the application does not break on its own by hitting a breakpoint.)  At this point, the Autos panel is empty.  Why is this?  Is it possible to view the auto variables (or locals for that matter) in break mode?

Note: My call stack panel displays just this: [External Code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pausing the application while it is executing (external) code in a class library, and you have the 'Just my code' option active in debugger options.

To see the call stack for external code:

'Tools' - 'Options' - 'Debugger' - 'General' and clear the 'Just My Code'.

Of course, if there is no debugging info available for the external code, and you pause while executing a method in the external code, the debugger will not be able to show the value for the 'locals' in the external method.

Comment: Thank you.  I did what you said, and it started giving me additional information (for example, it says mscorlib.pdb not loaded, and shows low-level variables in the Locals panel).  What I don't understand is, when I hit **Shift+F11**, instead of stepping out of whereever it is and stopping at the next statement, it continues to run the application, as if I pressed F5?

Comment: I suppose you mean Shift-F11 to step out.
As for your question: I am not really sure,but not surprised either: since there are no debugging symbols, the debugger seems to be unable to know where to stop executing after you tell it to continue to the caller...

Comment: Yes, sorry, just fixed it.

Comment: I think your best bet, is to set a breakpoint in your code at the point where the external method is called, and consider the external method as a singel work unit.

Comment: You are right, pausing does not really give you fine control.